What can I do when someone else is literally duplicating my PhD work?
I finished my PhD last year. I published three papers and submitted another one, so 4 from my work covering most of my research so far.
this year, I am seeing another new PhD student (he started his PhD just after I finished mine) and he is doing the same work except for one parameter he changed. He's begun winning prizes (presentation prizes) with that, using the same context, the same methodology. He has not published anything yet, but it sounds cringe and annoying, why would you work on my research and replicate it almost fully and not even mention or reference my work anywhere?
This guy also tried to approach me once to get the code I've worked on for 3-4 years so that he could change it and use it for his sake. I did not give him anything. Is there anything I can do to make sure he does not replicate my work and get the credit for that?

Is this with your advisor? Why should the group not continue on with the research, changing parameters to look at? Starting a new student on extending the work seems a normal starting point, as I have observed many times. Now, not referencing the previous work is not acceptable, but you haven't seen a publication yet.

'Is there anything I can do to make sure he does not replicate my work and gets the credit for that?' Publication.

Is that person in the same group? How do you know they get presentation prizes? Also, if you have published, just continue. Plus, try to give seminar or workshop talks. In the short run, talks have impact. But, in the long run, publications count. Also, since they approach you for code - ask them if they cite you (they don't, as you say, but it's a way of telling them they should...)

BTW, did you get prizes for your work? I think this is relevant information here for some responses.

"I did not give him anything." - ....

"... so that he could change it and use it for his sake. I did not give him anything." I urge you to think about the furtherment of Science and not just your personal career goals

If we change the order of paragraphs in your post, the story becomes "This guy first approached me and asked me for help and references. I refused to give him anything. Now he's not acknowledging my work even though it's clearly similar to his."

Also, there is a bit of a contradiction between "He has not published anything yet" and "not even mention or reference my work anywhere". Presumably the main place where he can mention and reference your work is on publications, which he doesn't have yet? So it seems the best thing to do is try to maintain good relations with him and make sure he references your work when he does publish. Although he probably should also mention your work during presentations, but don't think it's necessarily malicious if he doesn't.

"Is there anything I can do to make sure he does not replicate my work" Is this a joke? Having your work replicated is the best thing that could happen to you

They are not duplicating the work, they are extending it. The OP should be happy someone is picking it up while they go off and play with new things.

Which field is this ? Not sharing your code (after publication) would make me suspect that your code doesn't stand up to scrutiny.

"He's begun winning prizes (presentation prizes)..." Is he presenting his results in a way that differs from the way you did? (clearer for example).

Awesome! Somebody is actually interested in your thesis! You are probably in the upper 10 percentile.

Talk to him (and possibly his supervisor) about proper referencing
As is pointed out by others here, it is desirable for researchers to replicate and build on each other's work, and that is fine so long as there is proper attribution of sources using citation of previous work.  Since you have already published your papers on this topic, this new student should be citing that work and explaining to his reader how his own work builds on your papers.  This is part of the standard literature review that should be present in a paper/presentation.
You note that this student has not yet published any papers on this topic.  If and when he does, he will be expected to cite your work and the journals reviewing those papers will want him to be clear about what his own research adds to that previous work (e.g., adding a new parameter in a model/analysis).  It sounds like the present problem is with his presentations, which should also cite your work.
This issue should be reasonably simple to nip in the bud.  Since this is a new PhD student, it is likely that he is a novice in academic practice and he might not be aware that presentations should also cite key work.  A reasonable first action here would be to contact this student directly and talk to him about his presentations.  Let him know that it is usual for academic presentations to include citations to relevant work and tell him that you would have expected his presentations to cite your relevant papers.  You might also suggest to him that he seek some guidance from his supervisor on citation practices.  If necessary, you could also raise this issue directly with his supervisor, who would be more than happy to give him appropriate guidance.
For these types of situations, I also recommend that you apply a variant of Hanlon's razor: never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by incompetence.  Assume that you are dealing with a well-meaning researcher and begin by drawing the problem to their attention.  Trust in the safeguards of academic practice but try to nip problems like this in the bud with a friendly conversation in the first instance.

Replicability is literally one of the cornerstones of science. I would consider others trying to replicate my results -- assuming of course that they properly cite my earlier work -- about as high an honor as a scientist can get from their peers. Imagine that nobody cared enough about your work to want to replicate it!

"OP: replicate it almost fully and not even mention or reference my work anywhere?" - that's why I didn't upvote this response which otherwise makes a good point. But it seems OP does neither get the credit, nor the prizes. That's a problem.

@CaptainEmacs Reference where? There aren't any publications yet in which OP's work could be referenced.

The second sentence of the question says "I published three papers and submitted another one". Presumably those four are the publications which could be referenced. (And perhaps the dissertation itself. I'm sure it varies by field, but in mine, dissertations are commonly posted on arXiv and are citable.)

@DavidZ Wolfgang's comment is saying there are no publications yet by the student which could reference the OP's three or four papers.

@DanielHatton - it is unclear if the OP was present for the presentations to determine if his work was noted or not. Seems mostly to be sour grapes...

What do you mean by your research? do you mean it is not published yet? If it is published, no one should lose the freedom to do the research in the same direction just because s/he is from your former group.
If it is not published, why/how s/he know the methods or details you are using? If you are the one creating the methods, s/he is using your code, it is likely that you should at least be a co-author.
P.S. you seems very annoyed that this guy only change one parameter but getting many credit/prize. However sometime changing one important parameter do change everything. E.g. Superconductivity
